# How do you extend an existing module?

Tags: swift, module

In C#, it would look like this:

```
namespace QuartzCore {
    // extensions

    namespace Metal {
      // extensions
    }
}
```

or even

```
namespace QuartCore.Metal { extensions }
```

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: No. I'm confident that when I do, I'll remember to add the answer here. Is there a standard way for SO users to enforce that upon themselves?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with C#, but you can use [extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html) in Swift. Here's a simple example.

```
extension String {
    func count() -> Int {
        return countElements(self)
    }
}

var str = "Hello, playground"
str.count() //17
```

Comment: You can extend classes, structs, and enums this way, but the additions are scoped to your selected target. For simplicity, imagine what I need to be creating two global functions with the same signature, but one in a namespace (module) that exists already.